# CiviCRM Event - Event Confirmation EMail

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for the possibility to translate and modify the Event Confirmation EMail.

Installation:
Wordpress 5.3
CiviCRM 5.19
Thanks Felix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

You can edit any emails that are automatically sent from the System Workflow tab on this page - /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FmessageTemplates&reset=1

You're able to edit any email templates that are generated from the system such as event emails, membership emails and contribution emails.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Is this a url or file path? https://wp-admin/admin.php?page=/civicrm/admin/messageTemplates?reset=1 If I enter this path a error... Thank you

Comment: Ah my fault, I assumed the path was the same as Drupal. Have amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Felix

Comment: Glad it helped! If my answer solves your problem would you be able to approve it? :)